# SlipHover js Working everywhere but Iphones

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, mobile

I've created a basic details page that shows a product image and when you hover over it an overlay slides in with info on said product.
This is all accomplished with sliphover.js: https://wayou.github.io/SlipHover/

By default this is disabled on mobile devices so I commented out the following:

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { 
     alert("Mobile user detected");
}
```

And now it works on every mobile device except Iphones (IOS 13+), its even running on my old Ipad (IOS 9.3.5).
I'm working on a Windows laptop so in order to debug Safari I'm using the Inspect tool from https://inspect.dev/ ,here there are no errors and when I'm clicking the images on the phone, nothing continues to happen but in the debugging tool on my laptop the overlay slides in.

With zero errors and being more of an Android fan than Apple I'm struggling to come up with a cause.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this happens to anyone else I found the answer.
It looks like IOS kept adding an additional style to the body tag of:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

So the slider was working but not visible, simply change the above to:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible!important;
```

And the issues fixed.